# create array with multiple pixel or cell values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gdal, feature-extraction

I'm trying to calculate values of each pixel in numpy array for image brightness, slope aspect,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCtWq.jpg) NDVI value and elevation, but I'm stucked in making array with representation of each value what I will separately calculate on unique numpy arrays. I've read description for functions like stuck, concatenate etc. however I just can't realise what operation is proper to make that numpy array with multiple pixel values. Is it even possible to do so in Numpy library? I want to achieve this result: pixel with values [15.1254, 250, -0.3600,280] in array so I could iterate matrix and choose which pixel will be assign with let's say value 0 as  useless and other which will get value 1 as useful and apply it on RGB image in same array size as a filter to remove not needed spots in the image.

Answer (score 0):

It may be most simple to read these all into separate arrays. Alternatively, you can make a 3d numpy array and read values from each raster dataset into the array.